# How to include .map files wthin laravel app.css

Tags: laravel

I have less css included in bootstrap.css.map file. How to include .map files inside a laravel public/css/app.css.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix) then it provides a fluent API for defining Webpack build steps for your Laravel application using several common CSS and JavaScript pre-processors.

[Source maps](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#css-source-maps) can be activated by calling the `mix.sourceMaps()` method in your **webpack.mix.js** file.

```
mix.css('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
   .sourceMaps();
```